Insert thousands of documents into a chroma db
I have thousands of text files that I would like to add to a Chroma DB. I noticed that when I searched a certain number of documents, the search query no longer worked properly. I can no longer get the correct document back. Is there a best practice for managing very large amounts of data in vector databases. A smaller number of documents works very well, I only have problems with large amounts of data.
`pathFiles = "textfile_folder"
    loader = DirectoryLoader(path=pathFiles, glob="**/*.txt", loader_cls=TextLoader)
    docs = loader.load()

    oembed = OllamaEmbeddings(base_url="http://localhost:11434", model="nomic-embed-text:latest")
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=2500, chunk_overlap=500)
    texts = text_splitter.split_documents(docs)
    vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(texts, embedding=oembed,
                                        persist_directory='chromadb_name')`

I would like a code example or a precise explanation of how I should proceed so that I always get the correct results from the vector database, even with very large amounts of data

When you create a new chroma collection, you have to pass parameters for hnsw search algorithm:
https://cookbook.chromadb.dev/core/configuration/#hnsw-configuration.
If they are not tuned for your large dataset, the search will work badly.
It should be passed as metadata to this function of the chromadb client:
def get_or_create_collection(
    self,
    name: str,
    metadata: Optional[CollectionMetadata] = None,
    embedding_function: Optional[
        EmbeddingFunction[Embeddable]
    ] = ef.DefaultEmbeddingFunction(),  # type: ignore
    data_loader: Optional[DataLoader[Loadable]] = None,
) -> Collection:

e.g. where might be
metadata = {
    "hnsw:space": "cosine", 
    "hnsw:construction_ef": 600, 
    "hnsw:search_ef": 1000, 
    "hnsw:M": 60
}

These values should work for pretty huge number of embeddings.

The HNSW (Hierarchical Navigable Small World) algorithm is commonly used for approximate nearest neighbor (ANN) search, which is critical for efficient large-scale similarity search. When configuring HNSW for a large dataset in Chroma, tuning the parameters properly is essential to achieve optimal performance.
Number of Items

Small Dataset: Typically contains fewer than 1,000 items.
Medium Dataset: Usually contains between 1,000 and 100,000 items.
Large Dataset: Often contains over 100,000 items. In many cases, this threshold is much higher, and datasets with millions or billions of items are common in fields such as big data and high-performance computing.

Key HNSW Parameters

hnsw:space:

Description: Defines the metric space for measuring distances between vectors.
Common Values: "cosine", "l2", "ip"
Usage:

"cosine": Measures the cosine distance, useful for high-dimensional data where the angle between vectors is more important than their magnitude.
"l2": Uses Euclidean distance, suitable for general-purpose use.
"ip": Inner product, often used in machine learning for similarity search in high-dimensional spaces.




hnsw:construction_ef:

Description: The size of the dynamic list for the nearest neighbors during the graph construction.
Typical Range: 100 to 800
Effect: Higher values improve the accuracy of the graph but increase the construction time and memory usage.
Selection: For large datasets, a value around 400-600 is a good starting point, but it can be increased if more accuracy is needed.


hnsw:search_ef:

Description: The size of the dynamic list for the nearest neighbors during the search process.
Typical Range: 100 to 2000
Effect: Higher values increase the accuracy of the search results at the cost of longer search times.
Selection: A value around 500-1000 balances accuracy and search performance for large datasets.


hnsw:M:

Description: The maximum number of connections per node in the graph.
Typical Range: 5 to 100
Effect: Higher values improve accuracy and recall but increase memory consumption and construction time.
Selection: A value around 40-60 is usually effective for large datasets, ensuring a good balance between performance and resource usage.



Considerations for Tuning

Dataset Characteristics: Understand the nature of your data. For example, if your data is sparse and high-dimensional, "cosine" might be more appropriate than "l2".
Resource Availability: Ensure you have sufficient memory and computational resources, as higher values for construction_ef, search_ef, and M will increase memory usage and computational load.
Performance Requirements: Balance between construction time, search time, and accuracy based on your application needs. For instance, in real-time applications, lower search_ef might be preferred to reduce latency.

Sources
For more detailed information, refer to the official documentation and resources:

ChromaDB HNSW Configuration
HNSW Algorithm Paper - The original paper detailing the HNSW algorithm, its parameters, and their effects.


Thanks for this. Any resources where can I get an idea of what those values should be for what size of documents in collection?

@BikashGyawali I've added this to my post.
